# Dot net core action="." refers to controller but not action

Tags: http, asp.net-core

I have a controller named `CasesController` which in turn contains the following method:

```
    [HttpGet("Cases/Active")]
    public IActionResult GetActive()
    {
        return View("CaseList", _caseRepository.GetAll());
    }
```

Additionally the `CaseList.cshtml` file contains the following form:

```
<form class="form" method="get" action=".">
</form>
```

(in reality, this form is in a partial view rendered into the `CaseList` view and I want to use the same partial from a couple of different controller methods).  This form is used to `GET` back to the original page with some filter parameters to limit the number of records shown.

I expect this form to post back to `//Server/Cases/Active?FormField1=&FormField2=` Instead, the method name is left out of the URL that the `GET` is sent to: `//Server/Cases/?FormField1=&FormField2=`

How can I get the browser to recognize the full path back to the URL that produced the page?

Comment: Why would you use `.` for the action? That's your browser interpreting the URL, it's nothing to do with .Net Core.

Comment: Because I want to `GET` back to the current URL, which may vary (between `\Cases\Active` and `\Cases\Closed` depending on which view rendered the partial that contains the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the URL to be exactly the same as the page you are on but without the query string then instead of period (`.`) you need to use a question mark (`?`) or leave it blank. For example, assuming we are on a page with the URL `http://www.example.com/path/thing?value=1`, then the destination actions will be calculated like this:

```
.   =>  http://www.example.com/path/?form=1
?   =>  http://www.example.com/path/thing?form=1
```

Note: This is not really well defined anywhere. For example, you might find different browsers will give you different results. So it's quite bad practice to not specify the action URL.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll try the "?" as an immediate solution but will probably end up rewriting this partial view as a view component to get additional functionality -- which should then allow me to pass the destination url as a parameter.